# Strange mit-scheme interpreter behaviour

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp, mit-scheme

I have started to study SICP and used repl.it for code exercises. Now I want to write code locally. I have installed mit-scheme app and tried to move my code from repl.it to my computer.

But when I try to run the program that calculates the square root I get the very strange output with VERY BIG NUMBER as a result:

```
1 ]=> (define (square x) (* x x))
;Value: square

1 ]=> (define (abs x) (if (<= x 0) (- x) x))
;Value: abs

1 ]=> (define (average x y) (/ (+ x y) 2))
;Value: average

1 ]=> (define (improve guess x) (average guess (/ x guess)))
;Value: improve

1 ]=> (define (good-enough? new_guess old_guess)
    (< (abs (- new_guess old_guess)) 0.000000000000001))
;Value: good-enough?

1 ]=> (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (define new_guess (improve guess x))
    (if (good-enough? new_guess guess)
        new_guess
        (sqrt-iter new_guess x)))
;Value: sqrt-iter

1 ]=> (define (sqrt x) (sqrt-iter 1 x))
;Value: sqrt

1 ]=> (sqrt 16)
;Value: 271050543121377825343773346473727756780989953/67762635780343597914988263490310774732975168

1 ]=> 
End of input stream reached.
```

Here is the source code of the program, it works great at the repl.it:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (abs x)
  (if (<= x 0) (- x) x))

(define (average x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (improve guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(define (good-enough? new_guess old_guess)
  (< (abs (- new_guess old_guess)) 0.000000000000001))

(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (define new_guess (improve guess x))
  (if (good-enough? new_guess guess)
    new_guess
    (sqrt-iter new_guess x)))

(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-iter 1 x))

(sqrt 16)
```

**Note**: OS: MacOS Catalina, mit-scheme app version - 10.1.11

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Tip:  Multiply with 1.0 to convert a number to decimal. Example:  `(* 1.0 355/113)` .

Comment: Or, use the `exact->inexact` procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a big number, in fact it's just a rational number close to 4.0, take a careful look (I added extra spaces for clarity):

```
271050543121377825343773346473727756780989953 / 67762635780343597914988263490310774732975168
```

You'll get the desired result by switching to inexact arithmetic, just make your initial `guess` a decimal value:

```
(define (sqrt x) (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(sqrt 16)
=> 4.0
```

See the classic article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more details of *why* this is happening.

Comment: Thank you very much, @ÓscarLópez!

Answer (score 0):

This in scheme is called *coercion*.

You need to read the chapter about *generic functions* to understand how coercion works.